# How to change font color for Terminus package in sublime text 3

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3, settings

How to change font color for Terminus package in sublime text 3.

I went to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Terminus.sublime-settings

and then added this text below to the user setting but nothing happened. please help.

```
[{
     "theme": "user",
        "user_theme_colors": {      
         "04": "#0000ee",  // blue     
    },
},
]
```

Comment: What were you trying to change? That entry tells Terminus that it should use the color `#0000ee` whenever it wants to display blue text. If you want to change the color of text generally you need to modify the foreground color.

Comment: I was trying to change the text blue. I also tried the foreground attribute but not luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work is that the settings that you're using (as posted above) are broken. This appears to be a bug in Terminus because when you use `Preferences > Package Settings > Terminus > Settings`, the default file content should be `{ }` and not `[ ]`; `sublime-settings` files are JSON Objects, not JSON Lists (as `sublime-keymap` files are, for example).

So it should be enough to amend your settings file with content like the following; as noted in the comments above, the theme color you posted tells Terminus what color to use when it is representing the standard terminal color for blue, so this is modified to adjust the foreground color to be that color:

```
{
     "theme": "user",
    "user_theme_colors": {      
        "foreground": "#0000ee"
    },
}
```

In my testing here, changing the settings file and saving it is enough to see the change immediately reflected, so you should be able to have the settings open in one pane and a Terminal in another and be able to see results as you modify the scheme until things look right.

There's a command in the command palette labelled `Terminus Utilities: Generate User Theme` that forces a regeneration of the custom theme information, which may be of use in case the live update doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How to change the color of the text in Terminus look exactly like the Default Color I applied for the Ubuntu Terminal?

Comment: @an4s911 you'd have to make a custom color set like the above and manually set all of the colors to match. There's no automatic way to do it that I'm aware of. Ideally you would need the background color and all 16 of the foreground colors,

Comment: Actually, I found a way. It was by tweaking the `.bashrc` file and the `PS1` variable. I couldn't understand the code exactly but kinda understood what it meant and changed a line. Well, it worked. Thanks Anyway. If necessary, for anyone I would be pleased to show them.

Comment: @OdatNurd is it possible to change the prompt of the shell only for Sublime Text?

Comment: @amzon-ex from within a Terminus shell, the environment variable `TERM_PROGRAM` will be set to `"Terminus-Sublime"`; so you could adjust your `.bashrc` or similar to display a different prompt in that instance if desired.