# Terminus custom theming issue

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using the package `Terminus` on Sublime Text 3, and wish o change my default theme. I can't seem to be able to do it. I go to `Terminus Utilities: Select Theme` and select one, nothing happens. I edited the settings file to use custom colours instead, nothing happened. I used the option to `Generate User Theme` - no results. Please help.

**EDIT:**
When I try to open Terminus settings from *Preferences > Packages > Terminus > Settings*, this message is printed in the console:

```
Unable to open /C/Users/logic/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Terminus/Terminus.sublime-settings
```

But the settings file opens anyway.

Comment: Does this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60569669/2102457) help?

Comment: @mattst No, unfortunately not. I have seen this Q&A. My settings file is in the format of a JSON Object, as mentioned.

Comment: Are there any errors or messages printed in the console?

Comment: @MattDMo I added some information to the question.

Comment: If you go down to the `"user_theme_colors"` section of the user preferences (on the right), delete the leading `//` characters from some of the lines, customize them, then save the file, are the changes applied, either to a running terminal tab or to a new one?

Comment: I have experienced much frustration about the theming... It sounds random, but when I finally get the color options the way I like... then i return to the theme settings and everything has reverted back.